How to make deep links to iOS settings for reminders, without passing them through a shortcut?
Right now I have a reminder in the Reminders app with a URL attached, that passes in this deep link: prefs:root=DO_NOT_DISTURB* to the do not disturb section in the settings app, to a shortcut so the shortcut can open it: shortcuts://run-shortcut?name=Set%20Do%20Not%20Disturb&input=text&text=prefs:root=DO_NOT_DISTURB. Here's a sample shortcut to show it: https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/835b819d24c14386b8f6e072d034e3b3. The shortcut actions for doing so are in the photo below. I want a URL that can take me to the section in the Settings app directly from the reminder without having to pass it through a shortcut first.
I tried variations of URLs like prefs://root=DO_NOT_DISTURB, prefs://=DO_NOT_DISTURB, prefs://?root=DO_NOT_DISTURB, and prefs://DO_NOT_DISTURB from this page but they didn't work: https://github.com/bhagyas/app-urls?tab=readme-ov-file#settingsapp-preferences.
* There's a whole list of settings deep links if you want to see: https://github.com/FifiTheBulldog/ios-settings-urls/
(I took these screenshots on macOS but the link and shortcut only works on iOS)

